# Is there an App for Mac OS X that's like `Locale` for the iOS?

Tags: macos, iphone, locale

Locale is great because it can change my iPhone settings based on my location, time of day, etc. Is there something like that for Mac OS X that'll do something similar? Based on the WiFi I connect to, time of day, battery life, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little app called Sidekick that does just that.
You can download it at http://oomphalot.com/sidekick/

It's not free, but works great.

Answer (score 1):

[ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com) is a free alternative.